# Ubuntu + Unicorn: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler, unicorn

I have a problem to run unicorn on Ubuntu 16. When trying to run it - either manually (`service unicorn_myapp_staging restart`) or through Capistrano, I get this message: **You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)** (below is the full error track)

```
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:72:in `new'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:72:in `initialize'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:200:in `new'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:200:in `to_definition'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:12:in `evaluate'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:33:in `build'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `definition'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler.rb:94:in `setup'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

If I check the version of bundler, it seems to be fine:

```
bundle info bundler
  * bundler (2.1.4)
    Summary: The best way to manage your application's dependencies
    Homepage: https://bundler.io
    Path: /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-2.1.4
```

However, as is stated on the error message above, it looks that the used versions of ruby and bundler are old (2.3.3 and 1.14.3) compared to the newly upgraded ruby (2.6.3) and bundler (2.1.4).

Where do I set the correct versions of ruby and bundler for starting Unicorn? Is there a hidden config file on Ubuntu, where I need to specify it?

Comment: Like I've requested on [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60819733/3784008) you've recently posted about this app, please specify how you are building and deploying and starting this app. There are so many different possible configurations that the information you've provided so far is essentially useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix, looks like issue with Gemfile.lock. Try **removing** BUNDLED WITH from gemfile.lock.

Remove something like and build again

```
BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

Comment: Please update your question to provide more context.